# Orange 3 working with multiple datasets

Tags: dataset, model-evaluations, orange

I do not know if it is possible to somehow connect different datasets, that are related in some way, in Orange 3.
I am working with EEG multiple files (of channel values results) and one main data file "Ratings", consisting of subject number, score in idle mode and overall test score.

The point is that I want to make Test & Score to compare two algorithms, but I do not know how and what to do with all those files, to make it work.
F.E. obe subject from "Score" has two additional different dataset files ("low" and "high", both have same attributes of EEG channels and numeric values). So, how I imagine, I'd need to somehow use those high and low files, but they should be known (or somehow be connected) as "Ratings" dataset attribute "subject" number 1 data.

Sorry for my english but this problem is kinda hard to explain. Maybe I'll post an example of those files:

Main results are stored in "Ratings" dataset and final test score would be the target variable:

[image]

Then all of the subjects have two files, f.e. subject 1 has "sub01_hi" and "sub01_lo" with same channels but different values. There are 14 channels just containing values in both of those files. And that goes on for all of the subjects.

sub01_hi:
[image]

sub01_lo:
[image]
I want to use somehow those two files for evaluation by using different algorithms (like kNN or Bayes) and include the scores from "Ratings" dataset too, so that they'd be like categories or main target variables.

I'm just kinda lost here.. :/